# videojs v4.7.2 support for vast 3

Tags: video.js

We're using videojs v4.5.2 to show a preroll/postroll/midroll video. vast 2 is works well with video js 3.2.0 but not work with 4.5.2

Does videojs v4.5.2 has support for VAST 3?

Answer (score 0):

VAST support depends on which plugins you use, as advertising isn't part of the core player itself. Try using Google's IMA plugin.

https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima